# Discard part of lines and save arbitrary long numbers

Tags: c++, file-io

I have a `file.txt` like:

```
bqnt := 31

hqnt := 159

tqnt := 2

source := (6,53)

speed := 59
```

Where `6` and `53` are a coordinates and all the numbers that appear can have an arbitrary number of digits.

How can I save all the numbers that appear in a `file.txt` like this?

Comment: What is the maximum range of the numbers?

Comment: Do you want to keep some information and discard the rest?

Comment: Where do you want to save them?  What format, binary or text?

Comment: Have you searched StackOverflow for "c++ read file pair number"?

Comment: I want to save the numbers (31, 159, 2, 6, 53, 59) in different int variables e.g. int bqnt=31; int hqnt = 159; ecc...

Comment: What is the **exact** format of the input text?

Comment: the example is a copy of an exact format of the input text, numbers may vary but the format is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Next to the obvious solution, where you just keep the numbers in their string format, you can use an arbitrary precision integer library like the [GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library](https://gmplib.org/), which allows you to manipulate integers of arbitrary length.

Comment: I can also keep the numbers in their string format but I don't know how to take only the "last part" of each line where the numbers are

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems poorly worded, do you want to keep 6 and 53 or just one of them?  If you just want to accumulate strings of numeric characters, isidigit comes to mind.

You read each of the characters one at a time, if isdigit(c) you keep it, if not, you keep going, when you see a non-digit character, you move to the next line in your output, or you move to the next index in your array.

Comment: You are right, I did not explain that well: i want to keep both. The best thing would be to save the numbers as integers but I really don't know how...

Comment: As separate numbers or as a comma separated pair?

Comment: Answer adjusted.  More than this would be me doing your homework for you.